# SwipeRefreshLayout with ListView is taking all space available

Tags: android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

I thought I wouldn't have to write here, but I can't solve the problem! I have a `ListView` that has `wrap_content`, and below it `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`. Everythings workes fine, the `layout` is properly aligned when I populate the `ListView`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerTable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_modena"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:background="@drawable/table_border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/table11"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_saldo"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:background="@drawable/table_border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/table12"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_pagar"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:background="@drawable/table_border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/table13"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_cobrar"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:background="@drawable/table_border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/table14"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewTrefi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/headerTable" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider2"
    style="@style/dividerMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/listViewTrefi"
    android:alpha="0.5" />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    style="@style/SlidingTabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/divider2"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabLayoutTextAppearance" />

<wales.dahoum.mipyme.NonSwipeableViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/sliding_tabs" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But when I try to wrap `ListView` in `SwipeRefreshLayout`, the `layout is` taking all space available, and hides the other views below it - `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerTable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_modena"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:background="@drawable/table_border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/table11"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_saldo"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:background="@drawable/table_border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/table12"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_pagar"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:background="@drawable/table_border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/table13"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_cobrar"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:background="@drawable/table_border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/table14"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/headerTable">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewTrefi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider2"
    style="@style/dividerMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/swipe_refresh"
    android:alpha="0.5" />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    style="@style/SlidingTabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/divider2"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabLayoutTextAppearance" />

<wales.dahoum.mipyme.NonSwipeableViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_below="@id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the proper (left) and bad (right) align:

[image: the right align]
[image: the bad align]

What can you suggest to fix this?

Comment: So it sounds like you want to `match_parent` height to your `ListView`? (btw, why `ListView`, not `RecyclerView`)?

Comment: Partly, yes, I want `SwipeRefreshLayout` to **match** my `ListView` children's height, in other words, not to expand and have this empty space! All everywhere in the app I'm using `RecyclerView`, but here I did not have to change anything before. I'll try with `RecyclerView`, but I think the problem will persist. What can you suggest to me?

Comment: Try and add this line android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to TabLayout and ViewPager.

Comment: @deyanm I don't understand. What stops you from setting `match_parrent` on `SwipeRefreshLayout`?

Comment: If I set it, it takes all space below and hides the `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`.

Comment: But I have managed it to work, in very strange way. I get the children count with `recyclerView.getAdapter().getChildCount()` and then set the `SwipeRefreshLayout` height to sum of the children’s height. I know this is very bad solution, but it works at the moment and my `RecyclerView` will be max two rows.